# 英語が残っている: 自動ログインしたら出るメッセージ: Welcome back

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

[image: Welcome back]

> Welcome back, $fooBar$. You've been logged in.

Answer (score 1):

> Welcome back, $userLink$. You've been logged in.

適当翻訳

> $userLink$、お帰りなさい！自動的にログインされました。

適用翻訳

> $userLink$さん、おかえりなさい！自動的にログインしました。

Comment: 好みの問題かもしれませんが: 
`$userLink$さん、おかえりなさい！自動的にログインしました。`